# Exploring on API and webservices MS Office 365

Tags: web-services, api, office365

I have just started exploring Office 365.
I want to know that are there any APIs or Webservices available for Office 365 in **Java** and **Javascript**?

If yes then please provide me the links and guide me for how to start with it.

How much development is possible without C#/.Net?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I've used javascript to use the webservices by writing the below code in a javascript function, Hope this helps :)

```
var value = document.getElementById("LblTxt").value; 
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://<Provide the web service link here>/<Provide the function name of the webservice here>"+"/"+value,               
          success: function (msg) {                                    
             var response= msg.text;//Note use Boolean variable if the webservice returns a Boolean vale                
              $('#status').html(response);  
               writeToExcel(response);
          },
          error: function (result) {                                   
               $('#status').innerHTML = "Unavailable";
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I'm doing the same as you, the only way you can code for sharepoint/ office365 is by creating a sandbox solution which has many limitations.

More info can be found at their own forum: http://community.office365.com/en-us/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of samples out there which are non managed code approaches to talking to Office 365 and pure play JavaScript. In  actual fact the whole SharePoint Hosted App model is using only client side code with HTML and JavaScript. The best place to start is http://dev.office.com/.
I have recently presented at Microsoft TechEd NA 2014 where I showed a fully client side AngularJS SharePoint Hosted App using the CSOM and REST APIs. The recording is available at http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B229#fbid=BpHXCwlr8Va. In this presentation I use a full code sample which is available on Github at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Learning-Path-Manager-Code-Sample

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the new [Office 365 API Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892%28v=office.15%29.aspx).  It's based on REST/JSON/OAuth2, so any language that can "talk HTTP" can use it.  Beware that it's still in Preview though and not yet for production usage.

If you are interested in Exchange in Office 365, then you can look at [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).  This is a SOAP based protocol and has very good support/coverage for the API.  There is an [EWS wrapper for Java](https://github.com/jlaws/ews-java), but it doesn't seem to be actively maintained.

Sorry, I'm not as versed in the APIs for Sharepoint Online, Lync, OneDrive etc. but I know the Office 365 API Preview is intended to converge these app specific APIs into a single framework.